# How to make the text in the text label not able to edit and if something is typed, it disappears?

Tags: javascript, text, textlabel

I'm having trouble with making login page, beaucose I don't know which label is for login, and which is for password. Can anyone help me please?

I tried to make a text invisible, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Share what you have been done so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.